# How to round without Math#round?

Tags: java, math

So it's easy to round the tenths place with just doing something like:

```
int y;
double x = 2.5;

y = (int) (x+.5);
```

but how would you go about rounding to the hundredths or even thousands place without using `Math.round()`?

Comment: That isn't full proof because you have floating point arithmetic errors.  (Including the first way) and in this way you could get an integer overflow error as well.

Comment: *Why* do you want to avoid using `Math.round`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can multiply the original number by a power of 10 so that the desired place to round is in the unit's place, apply the "add half and round" method you already have, then divide the same power of 10, so the resulting number is now back to the original scale.

For hundredths:

1. Declare `y` to be a `double`.  This is so that rounding `2.125` to the hundredths' place will result in `2.13`, not `2`.
2. Multiply the `x` value by `100.0`.
3. Add `0.5`.
4. Cast to `int`.  (Or `long` for more precision.)
5. Divide by `100.0`.

Ex.: Rounding `2.125` to the hundredths' place.
1. 2.125 * 100.0 is `212.5`.
2. 212.5 + 0.5 is `213.0`.
3. `213.0` cast to `int` is `213`.
4. `213` divided by `100.0` is `2.13`.

For thousandths, the procedure is the same, except that `100.0` is replaced by `1000.0`.

The above method is subject to floating-point errors due to the finite precision of the `double` floating-point type.

You can also convert your value to a `BigDecimal`.  Then you can use [`BigDecimal`'s `round` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#round-java.math.MathContext-).  It takes a [`MathContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html) that allows you directly to round to the desired precision.

Comment: Shouldn't you have the integer conversion step in your list of steps?

Comment: @juhist Yes, I forgot that!  Updated.

Answer (score 2):

public class Decimal {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double xd = 2.125;
    double mult = xd * 100.0;
    double add = mult + 0.5;
    int reuslts = (int) add;

    double result = reuslts / 100.0;

    System.out.println(result);// 2.13
}
```

}

Comment: for more clarification i have write step by step