# How to round down without math.floor in java

Tags: java, rounding

How to round down without using `math.floor` or any math library function ?

Examples

- `3.999 = 3`
- `56.22 = 56`
- `3.6 = 3`
- `9.1 = 9`

I've tried the following but I'm only getting `0`

```
public int roundDown(double n){
    return (int) n/1000*10000;
}
```

Comment: Casting alone will do what you want. IOW truncation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round without Math#round?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264130/how-to-round-without-mathround)

Answer (score 3):

Just do cast to `int`

```
return (int) n;
```

---

To understand the problem with your code is that  `n` is casted to `int` **before** the division `n / 1000` so that makes an int division, you need more parenthesis, also multiply by `1000` and not `10000`

```
return (int) (n / 1000 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple divide and cast to an integer value. Use long to achieve greater range for your numbers.

```
int res = (int) floatValue;
long res = (long) floatValue;
```

Java will always round towards zero.

- If the number's greater than zero, it'll round down.
- If the number's less than zero, it'll round up.

The trick you're 'using' helps with achieving rounding to certain digits.
Again, use `double` for improved accurarcy and range.

```
public class RoundWithDigits {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final double[] testNumbers = new double[] { -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5343554, 15.7 };

        for (int preserveDigits = 0; preserveDigits < 5; preserveDigits++) {
            System.out.println("Preserving digits: " + preserveDigits);
            for (int i = 0; i < testNumbers.length + 5; i++) {
                final double randomNumber = (i < testNumbers.length) ? testNumbers[i] : Math.random() * 100 - 50;
                System.out.println("\tRandom:\t" + randomNumber);
                System.out.println("\tRound:\t" + round(randomNumber, preserveDigits));
                System.out.println("\tRTZero:\t" + roundTowardsZero(randomNumber, preserveDigits));
                System.out.println("\tRUp:\t" + roundCeiling(randomNumber, preserveDigits));
                System.out.println("\tRDown:\t" + roundFloor(randomNumber, preserveDigits));
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("All done.");
    }



    static public double round(final double pValue, final int pPreserveDigits) {
        final long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, pPreserveDigits);
        final long roundedMult = Math.round(pValue * factor);
        return (double) roundedMult / factor;
    }
    static public double roundTowardsZero(final double pValue, final int pPreserveDigits) {
        final long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, pPreserveDigits);
        final long roundedMult = (long) (pValue * factor);
        return (double) roundedMult / factor;
    }
    static public double roundCeiling(final double pValue, final int pPreserveDigits) {
        final long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, pPreserveDigits);
        long roundedMult = (long) (pValue * factor);
        if (roundedMult != pValue * factor && pValue > 0) ++roundedMult;
        return (double) roundedMult / factor;
    }
    static public double roundFloor(final double pValue, final int pPreserveDigits) {
        final long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, pPreserveDigits);
        long roundedMult = (long) (pValue * factor);
        if (roundedMult != pValue * factor && pValue < 0) --roundedMult;
        return (double) roundedMult / factor;
    }

}
```